# App Rejected - Uploaded New binary - In App Purchase - Developer action needed - Waiting for review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I submitted app with its newly created ***in-App purchases*** but its rejected since there were some in-app guidelines was missed by me, and in-app purchases status changed to  "Developer action needed",

then I changed as per guideline, uploaded a new build, and after few hours I searched for how to tackle "Developer action needed" case for ***in-App purchases***, I changed its description save it and changed back to its original after it ***in-App purchases*** went for "waiting for review", After few hours I edited new screenshot when ***in-App purchases*** were in "waiting for review", and It's Friday afternoon in India here when I did this.

now I have to select from **In-App Purchases+ section** below **General App Information section** in Application version for **app submission**, but I don't see them in list when I tap on +, since they are in "waiting for review". I am totally stuck Since **I cannot submit my app build without in-App purchase selected with it**.

*Note: when I used ***in-App purchases***, It means these are the auto Renewal in-App purchase products which I am talking about.

How much time will it take for my in-App purchase "Waiting for review" to next status?

Did I do something wrong? If yes please suggest me some actions to take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our App is submitted now, below is my experience how It got succeeded.

- Title of publication or serviceLength of subscription (time period and content or services provided during each subscription period) should be shown clearly to the user in your app
- Price of subscription and price per unit should be shown clearly.
- We need to show some in-app purchase guidelines inside app before purchase  (for auto renewal)

  The following information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription:

  • Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase

  • Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the current period

  • Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period, and identify the cost of the renewal

  • Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after purchase

  • Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will be forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that publication, where applicable

- should have following links inside your app while purchasing on the screen somewhere. These also should be on app description on itune.

  • A link to the terms of use
  • A link to the privacy policy
- When app was rejected and in-App purchases went for "Developer action needed" status. I changed its description save it and changed back to its original after it ***in-App purchases*** went for "waiting for review". At this stage, you don't need to add your ***in-App purchases*** in ***In-App Purchases+*** section below ***General App Information*** section in Application version for app submission. They automatically will get reviewed with your app if you resubmit with all above points having taken care of.
- Last but not least, You have to mention your ***in-App purchases*** products in app description of your app's itune connect account, have to tell auto renewal use of guidelines there too. add there both links for ***the terms of use*** and ***the privacy policy***

Best of luck. :)

Comment: your comment contains everything we should consider :)) thanks for writing it in detail!

Answer (score 1):

Nitesh, looks like you did everything right. In-App and the App itself can (but must not) be reviewed independent from each other.

Usually I send In-App changes or new In-Apps long time before I submit the App. This way, they can be reviewed first and everything can be sorted out way before I submit my App (Update). In your case, as far as I understand what you were writing, you have both, the App and the In-App in "In Review".

That's ok and you just need to be patient.

Maybe both will be reviewed at the same time but that's not certain.

However, I would suggest to set your App to "Manual release" because if your App gets reviewed before the In-App it may end up on the Store and the In-App would not work. Normally I would expect Apple to not release an App where an In-App would not work but I had a situation where Apple released an App anyway. So as mentioned, set your App to "Manual release" and release it, once both, the App and the In-App has been reviewed.

Even though I had Apps release on Saturdays and even more often on Sundays, in most cases I had to wait until Monday or even Tuesday for the Review when I submitted an App on Friday.

Regarding your question about the review time, normally, In-App reviews are quick. It's basically just a formal check. Sometimes they happen on the same day. Apps are currently 2 days (see http://appreviewtimes.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited my question again since I see maybe my description was not enough to describe my situation.  My app is not submitted yet its "prepare for submission" state I am just waiting for my in-app-purchase-product's "waiting for review" status to change so that I can attach them in my build to submit.  My app is rejected actually twice first time when I forgot to attach in-app-purchase-product, second due to missing guidelines, so This time I know I cant proceed submission without in-app-purchase-products.

Comment: Has your InApp and your App been released meanwhile ? I had two Apps that were already released during this time.

Comment: hm, Nitesh seems to no longer interested in answering - or voting.

Comment: Sorry Marcus, I just answered the question. I shared all those steps I have taken care of app submission.